# Spark scala window count max

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have following df:-

| result | state | clubName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| win | XYZ | club1 |
| win | XYZ | club2 |
| win | XYZ | club1 |
| win | PQR | club3 |

I need state wise max wining clubName

```
val byState =Window.partitionBy("state").orderBy('state)
```

I tried creating a window but does not helps..

Expected Result :-

Some like this in sql

```
select temp.res
(select count(result) as res
from table
group by clubName) temp
group by state
```

e.g

| state | max_count_of_wins | clubName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2 | club1 |

Comment: What do you mean by state wise max wining clubName, can you add the expected result aswell ?

Comment: added as per comment @koiralo

Comment: `club1` and `club2` have the same number of wins. why do you choose `club1`? and why there is no row for state `PQR` in your result?

Comment: club1 has one win. Why does your sample result has two? In general, most of the time, if you can express what you need in sql, you can just use `spark.sql` to get it. Your sql isn't actually valid though. Perhaps, it makes sense to start with fixing that.

Comment: sorry..I have edited the input.. @blackbishop

Comment: @Dima I need to use dataframe apis not sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the win count for each club, then assign a rank for each club ordered by wins, and filter those rows with rank = 1.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "wins", 
    count(when(col("result") === "win", 1))
    .over(Window.partitionBy("state","clubName"))
).withColumn(
    "rn", 
    row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("state").orderBy(desc("wins")))
).filter("rn = 1").selectExpr("state", "wins as max_count_of_wins", "clubName")

df2.show
+-----+-----------------+--------+
|state|max_count_of_wins|clubName|
+-----+-----------------+--------+
|  PQR|                1|   club3|
|  XYZ|                2|   club1|
+-----+-----------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a SQL-dialect with SparkSQL (find doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html)):

```
df.sql("""
SELECT tt.name, tt.state, MAX(tt.nWins) as max_count_of_wins
FROM (
  SELECT t1.clubName as name, t1.state as state, COUNT(1) as nWins
  FROM Table1 t1
  WHERE t1.result = 'win'
  GROUP BY state, name
  ) as tt
GROUP BY tt.state;
""")
```

where the table in the dataframe would be named `Table1` and your dataframe `df`.

p.s. if you want to try it yourself use the initialization

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`result` varchar(3), `state` varchar(3), `clubName` varchar(5))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`result`, `state`, `clubName`)
VALUES
    ('win', 'XYZ', 'club1'),
    ('win', 'XYZ', 'club2'),
    ('win', 'XYZ', 'club1'),
    ('win', 'PQR', 'club3')
;
```

on http://sqlfiddle.com.